# Probability that one number divides another of two randomly chosen numbers

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, probability-theory

I've met the following problem:

There's a set of numbers $\{1, 2, 3, ..., 2n\}$. After that we randomly choose two numbers $a$ and $b$. What's the probability that $a$ divides $b$ or $b$ divides $a$.

Comment: Is there any particular reason why the interval is assumed to have even length? (Do you expect the result to be easier for this case than for the odd case?)

Comment: You are looking for $c$ with $a=bc\leq2n$, or $c\leq2n/b$, which is the number of grid points below the curve $y=2n/x$.  That is roughly the area below the curve.

Comment: @Empy2, it's very interesting idea, thank you!

Comment: @Mark van Leeuwen, unfortunately, I don't know. I guess it's has some role.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An expression for the number of pairs $(a,b)\in\{1,\dots,m\}^2$ that satisfy $[a\mid b\text{ or }b\mid a]$ is:$$2\sum_{r=1}^m\lfloor\frac{m}{r}\rfloor-m$$

For every $r\in\{1,\dots,m\}$ there are $\lfloor\frac{m}{r}\rfloor$ multiples of $r$ in the set $\{1,\dots,m\}$.

Taking $\lfloor\frac{m}{r}\rfloor$ twice we get the number of pairs plus $m$ (because pairs on the diagonal are counted twice).

So an expression for the probability that a pair satisfies the condition is:$$\left[2\sum_{r=1}^m\lfloor\frac{m}{r}\rfloor-m\right]/m^2$$

In your case we must substitute $m=2n$.

Comment: I ment that a | b OR b | a, but you mean a | b AND b | a

Comment: Then IMV the terminology "divide each other" is not correct or at least confusing.

Comment: I adapted my answer to the condition you mention now.